# Why is my CSS class not being used in chrome but in Safari and Firefox?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with a css class which is used in Safari and Firefox but not in Chrome. Here is the code:

main.css

```
.stylized_button_red {
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white;
}
.stylized_button_red:hover {
    background-color: #cc0000 !important;
}

.stylized_button_orange {
    background-color: #FFA500 !important;
    color: white;
}
.stylized_button_orange:hover {
    background-color: #FF8C00 !important;
}
```

template.html

```
<td class="action_buttons">
    <input type="button" id="orange_button_{{ button.id }}" class="stylized_button stylized_button_smaller stylized_button_tight stylized_button_orange" data-role="none" value="{% trans 'orange button' %}" />
    <input type="button" id="red_button_{{ button.id }}" class="stylized_button stylized_button_smaller stylized_button_tight stylized_button_red" data-role="none" value="{% trans 'red button' %}" />
</td>
```

The styling for the red and orange button are in the same file.
The red button works on all browsers. The orange button only works on Safari and Firefox. 
If I change the orange button to a red button in the template it works on all browsers.
If I change the color in the css file from orange to a different color it does not work on chrome.

The other button classes such as `stylized_button_tight` work on all browsers and are also defined in the same main.css.

I have reloaded the page multiple times, restarted chrome and restarted the development server there was no difference.

I tried to research this and found only people describing that the color in chrome was rendered slightly different than in the other browsers. I could not find an answer for this specific situation.

Comment: It is working for me on Google Chrome https://jsfiddle.net/5xwwwh6t/

Comment: I'm with @VikrantSingh seems fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwpWdM

Comment: Make sure you have no spelling mistakes of your class names in both css and html files in your original code.

Comment: @VikrantSingh I copy pasted the names so that I am sure that it is the same. There is still no difference. What else could be going on in my code that causes this behaviour?

Comment: I think it is a problem in the style sheet like a forgotten `;`, invalid selector or a misplaced character somewhere between the red and orange selectors which S and FF tolerate, but C does not.

Comment: @Christoph I copied the css part from main.css without changing it. There is nothing in between the red and orange selectors.